# Scrapy - 301 redirect in shell

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I can not find a solution to the following problem. I am using Scrapy (latest version) and am trying to debug a spider.
Using `scrapy shell https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/301.html` -> it does not follow the redirect ( it is using a default spider to get the data). If I am running my spider it follows the 301 - but I can not debug.

How can you make the shell to follow the 301 to allow one to debug the final page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scrapy uses Redirect Middleware for redirects, however it's not enabled in shell. Quick fix for this:

```
scrapy shell "https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/301.html"
fetch(response.headers['Location'])
```

Also to debug your spider you probably want to inspect the response your spider is receiving:

```
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
def parse(self, response)
    inspect_response(response, self)
    # the spider will stop here and open up an interactive shell during the run
```

Comment: thanks! This seems to be a quick fix which allows me to continue!

Comment: @Pixelartist no problem, see my edit for more info regarding debugging spiders properly.

Comment: I think the additional edit is kind of the full solution. I was hoping that you can configure the shell behavior but with this - it solves it.